# Magento - customise a category grid in homepage

Tags: templates, layout, magento, magento-1.4

I want to customise the design of a category grid in homepage, and don't touch to the others grid desgin in intern pages.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't need a new block. Just copy the template and change references to it in the layout files appropriately.

Comment: yes, I have done like that, but I have a problem with duplicating the css clss products-grid for my custom phtml file, I have whether all products in one column or all products in one line !! :(

Answer (score 1):

You should create new block for this data. Get data from magento models. And use you own template for this block.